# Unrecognized selector woes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, selector

I'm puzzled... I have this function "colorWithHexString"... when I include it in the viewcontroller that's calling it then it works fine.  But when I move it to a separate "BSJax" class and call it with the same input parameter it throws an unrecognized selector error.  Here's the call:

```
BSjax *bsjax = [BSjax new];
NSString *hexString = [NSString stringWithString:@"CCCCFF"];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[bsjax colorWithHexString:hexString]];
```

I'm pretty sure there's something about the way I'm calling the function that prevents it from working as a bsjax method.  Any feedback will be appreciated.

BSjax.h includes:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)stringToConvert;
```

... and BSjax.m includes:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)stringToConvert
{
    NSString *cString = [[stringToConvert stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];

    // String should be 6 or 8 characters
    if ([cString length] < 6) NSLog(@"colorWithHexString called with parameter < 6 characters in length");

    // strip 0X if it appears
    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];

    if ([cString length] != 6) NSLog(@"colorWithHexString called with parameter != 6 characters in length");

    // Separate into r, g, b substrings
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 2;
    NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 2;
    NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 4;
    NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    // Scan values
    unsigned int r, g, b;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)
                           green:((float) g / 255.0f)
                            blue:((float) b / 255.0f)
                           alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: post your method definition for colorWithHexString and please post where it is defined (which file)

Comment: @coneybeare... k, added declaration & definition... what's puzzling is that when I move the function to the viewcontroller itself (without changing anything... well, i do change it to be a private method instead of public... it works like a charm)

Comment: I'm very bad at understanding pointers and memory management and wonder if I'm supposed to retain my hexString variable or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to call a class method on an instance.

Notice the `+`:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)stringToConvert;
```

It means you can only call the method as `[ClassName classmethod]`

And then here you are trying to use the method with an instance `[instanceObject classmethod]`:

```
BSjax *bsjax = [BSjax new];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[bsjax colorWithHexString:hexString]];
```

Try changing it to:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[BSjax colorWithHexString:hexString]];
```

And that should set you straight.

Comment: HA!  Nice.  I'm so incompetent in this language... I really have no business even attempting this project.  I thought the +/- represented public/private.  Your suggestion worked like a charm... ^1 & marked as answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is colorWithHexString declared in `@interface BSjax` in a header, and did you #import that header into the source file where the error is reported?

Edit:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)stringToConvert;
```

The above code (the +) declares a class method, meaning it should be called with the class name.  You are calling it with an instance of the class, for which it is not defined.  Try:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[BSjax colorWithHexString:hexString]];
```